# $A \times \left(B \times C\right) \cong \left(A \times B\right) \times C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I am proving the associativity of set products:

> Suppose $A$, $B$ and $C$ are linearly ordered sets. Then
> \begin{equation*}
> A \times \left(B \times C\right) \cong \left(A \times B\right) \times C,
> \end{equation*}
> where the order of products is anti-lexicographic.

Proof. Define a function $f: A \times \left(B \times C\right) \to \left(A \times B\right) \times C$ such that
\begin{equation*}
\forall a \in A, \forall b \in B, \forall c \in C, f\left(a,\left(b,c\right)\right) = \left(\left(a,b\right),c\right).
\end{equation*}
It is obvious that $f$ is bijective. Next we shall prove the following statement:
\begin{equation*}
\left(a_{1},\left(b_{1},c_{1}\right)\right) <_{A \times \left(B \times C\right)} \left(a_{2},\left(b_{2},c_{2}\right)\right) \Longleftrightarrow \left(\left(a_{1},b_{1}\right),c_{1}\right) <_{\left(A \times B\right)\times C} \left(\left(a_{2},b_{2}\right),c_{2}\right).
\end{equation*}
Naturally, assume $\left(a_{1},\left(b_{1},c_{1}\right)\right) <_{A \times \left(B \times C\right)} \left(a_{2},\left(b_{2},c_{2}\right)\right)$. This condition can be decomposed into the following categories:

- $c_{1} <_{C} c_{2}$
- $c_{1} = c_{2}$ and $b_{1} <_{B} b_{2}$
- $c_{1} = c_{2}$ and $b_{1} = b_{2}$ and $a_{1} <_{A} a_{2}$

If $c_{1} <_{C} c_{2}$, then it is clear that $\left(\left(a_{1},b_{1}\right),c_{1}\right) <_{\left(A \times B\right)\times C} \left(\left(a_{2},b_{2}\right),c_{2}\right)$. Next, if $c_{1} = c_{2}$ and $b_{1} <_{B} b_{2}$, then it is also clear that $\left(\left(a_{1},b_{1}\right),c_{1}\right) <_{\left(A \times B\right)\times C} \left(\left(a_{2},b_{2}\right),c_{2}\right)$. Finally, if $c_{1} = c_{2}$ and $b_{1} = b_{2}$ and $a_{1} <_{A} a_{2}$, we also have $\left(\left(a_{1},b_{1}\right),c_{1}\right) <_{\left(A \times B\right)\times C} \left(\left(a_{2},b_{2}\right),c_{2}\right)$.

Next, assume that $f\left(a_{1},\left(b_{1},c_{1}\right)\right) <_{\left(A\times B\right)\times C} f\left(a_{2},\left(b_{2},c_{2}\right)\right)$, that is,
\begin{equation*}
\left(\left(a_{1},b_{1}\right),c_{1}\right) <_{\left(A \times B\right)\times C} \left(\left(a_{2},b_{2}\right),c_{2}\right).
\end{equation*}
Then, we have the following categories:

- $c_{1} <_{C} c_{2}$
- $c_{1} = c_{2}$ and $b_{1} <_{B} b_{2}$
- $c_{1} = c_{2}$ and $b_{1} = b_{2}$ and $a_{1} <_{A} a_{2}$

The argument is similar to our previous one. Thus, we may conclude that 
\begin{equation*}
\left(a_{1},\left(b_{1},c_{1}\right)\right) <_{A \times \left(B \times C\right)} \left(a_{2},\left(b_{2},c_{2}\right)\right) \Longleftrightarrow \left(\left(a_{1},b_{1}\right),c_{1}\right) <_{\left(A \times B\right)\times C} \left(\left(a_{2},b_{2}\right),c_{2}\right).
\end{equation*}
As a result, we have 
\begin{equation*}
A \times \left(B \times C\right) \cong \left(A \times B\right) \times C.
\end{equation*}

I am learning elementary set theory on my own. Is it a solid proof?

Comment: What order are you using on the product?

Comment: @egreg Anti-lexicographic. I have added the information in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re really done once you show that

$$\langle\langle a_1,b_1\rangle,c_1\rangle<_{(A\times B)\times C}\langle\langle a_2,b_2\rangle,c_2\rangle\tag{1}$$

and

$$\langle a_1,\langle b_1,c_1\rangle\rangle<_{A\times(B\times C)}\langle a_2,\langle b_2,c_2\rangle\rangle\tag{2}$$

are both equivalent to the assertion that either

- $c_1<_C c_2$, or
- $c_1=c_2$ and $b_1<_Bb_2$, or
- $c_1=c_2$, $b_1=b_2$, and $a_1<_Aa_2$.

You could, however, stand to say a bit more to justify these equivalences. For $(1)$ it’s pretty clear, but for $(2)$ I’d say more than you did:

> $(2)$ means that either $\langle b_1,c_1\rangle<_{B\times C}\langle b_2,c_2\rangle$, or $\langle b_1,c_1\rangle=\langle b_2,c_2\rangle$ and $a_1<_Aa_2$. This in turn means that either $c_1<_Cc_2$, or $c_1=c_2$ and $b_1<_Bb_2$, or $c_1=c_2$, $b_1=b_2$, and $a_1<_Aa_2$.